# difference between regular expression with and without group '( )'?

Tags: python, regex

There are two different codes which produce two different result but I don't know how those differences arise.

```
>>>re.findall('[a-z]+','abc')
['abc']
```

and this one with group:

```
>>> re.findall('([a-z])+','abc')
['c']
```

why the second code yield character `c` ?

Comment: because you're repeating the capturing group.. try `([a-z]+)`. Same as `(.+)` and `(.)+`

Answer (score 0):

In your last regex pattern (`([a-z])+`), you are repeating a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (`()`). And doing this will return only last iteration.  So you get the last letter, which is `c`

But in your first pattern (`[a-z]+`), you are repeating a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[]`), and this doesn't behave the same as a capturing group. It returns all the iterations.